# What do I get in return for offering a gift to the priest

Tags: android, the-bards-tale

I'm playing **The Bard's Tale** for android. In the first town (Houton if I remember correctly ) there is a priest in one of the houses and he ask for donation. It can be a 1, 50 or 100 coins gift.

Do I get anything for that donation?

Comment: just double checking, we are talking about [The Bard's Tale](http://store.steampowered.com/app/41900/The_Bards_Tale/)?

Comment: @Memor-X yes, that's the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small and medium donations gives healing to your character.

Though some of my friends say large donations unlocks extras in the menus. I haven't tried this myself for i haven't collected 100 coins yet.